# WP8 Can't Update listbox item in XML file after using hardware back button

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi All i have a list box and i am saving list box selected item in XML file thats working fine but the problem is that when i will close my app and reopen and add more value to list box my previous value is removed form the xml file and listbox also how i can save my current added value and previous value in xml file i am using following code :

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,10,15,0">
            <ListBox Name="list_location" Tap="list_location_Tap"  Foreground="Black">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>

            <ListBox Name="list_locationAdd"  Foreground="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
```

and i am using following back end code :

```
 private void list_location_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show(MsgConst.ADD_LOCATION, "Location", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {

                try
                {
                    //list_locationAdd.Items.Add(list_location.SelectedItem); 

                    Prediction pItem = list_location.SelectedItem as Prediction;
                    App.professionalId = pItem.description;

                    list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = App.professionalId;
                    list_locationAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    list_location.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    XmlWriterSettings x_W_Settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    x_W_Settings.Indent = true;
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = ISF.OpenFile("La.xml", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
                            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, x_W_Settings))
                            {
                                if (list_locationAdd != null)
                                {
                                    data.Add(new Prediction() { description = App.professionalId });
                                    list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
                                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);

                                }


                            }

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

                using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream str = ISF.OpenFile("La.xml", FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
                        ObservableCollection<Prediction> data = (ObservableCollection<Prediction>)serializer.Deserialize(str);
                        if (list_locationAdd != null)
                        {
                            this.list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
                            list_locationAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

while adding values into xml, second time you open the app, you might flush the data that's already exist in the xml file.

Check your back-end code where you adding selected values into xml file. you might find some issues there.

**Possible Solution :-**

do not rewrite whole xml file everytime app opens, but just append the values into existing content of xml file.

Hope that helps..!
For further help, provide your `Back-End` code here.

Comment: sir Keval Langalia can you please send me your email id that i will send my back end code please sir..

Comment: Thanks Keval Langalia sir i have updated my question please check it now.